# How to use PHP Variables in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have 2 PHP Variables: `$category1` and `$category2`

I want the URL to be like this:

```
?category1=$category1&category2=$category2&q=str
```

I only know PHP, I have very less knowledge of JS/Jquery, can someone help me in this small thing?

I tried this:

```
var category1 = '<?php echo $category1; ?>';
var category2 = '<?php echo $category2; ?>';
```

But, idk what to write here

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
```

Comment: so the only issue is string concatenation in javascript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/best-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Comment: Yeah probably..

Comment: @rtfm i do not understand anything in that question. Bcz i have less knowledge of JS. This is very small thing, it can be answered in 30 sec :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+ str +"&category1="+ category1 +"&category2=" +category2+,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var category1 = '<?php echo $category1; ?>';
var category2 = '<?php echo $category2; ?>';
var url = "category1="+category1+"&category2="+category2+"&q=str";
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?"+url,true);
```

You will get your url just like you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q=" + str + "&category1=" + category1 + "&category2=" + category2,true);
```

Use + to concat the string