# How to pass a variable in java script in between qoutes or concatenation

Tags: javascript

I want to pass the info variable in the  tag's attribute DATA.
But Variable info is not passing , please help me how i can use info variable correctly.
Thanks in Advance.

```
 document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="update_league.php?updated_id=info"></object>';
```

Comment: do this   document.getElementsByClassName('modal-body')[0].innerHTML='<object type="text/html" data="update_league.php?updated_id='+info+'"></object>';

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/best-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes, use element.dataset. You might need to rename the `data` attribute to `data-something`.