# How to pass a variable with url on javascript fetch() method?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm trying to fetch data from URL with GET method on javascript,

```
fetch('/api/staffattendance/{makedate}')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(res => {
    //this.staffs = res.data;
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

How can I pass the variable here:

```
fetch('/api/staffattendance/{makedate}')
```

Like this

[image]

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Did you search a bit? Maybe `\`my_string${my_variable}\`` is what you are looking for. Or string concatenation. There are plenty of solution available and well documented

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use [`Template Literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Most efficient way to concatenate strings in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696632/most-efficient-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6):

One method is the string concatenation but `js` has introduced another mechanism called `template literal`:

Embed the string with `` and user variable with ${makedate}.

```
`/api/staffattendance/${makedate}`
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried all solution mention in this. but nothing worked. I want to fetch data for "vall" id, please help me.                                          fetch('https://performancetestdmb.azurewebsites.net/api/products/'+vall+'/Category2')

Answer (score 2):

You can also put the string in backticks ``, and include `${yourVariable}` where you want your variable, example:

```
  fetch(`/api/staffattendance/${makedate}`)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      //this.staffs = res.data;
      console.log(res.data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Comment: How can I use this in ejs?

Answer (score 1):

Did you encompass the whole URL in acutes ( these little guys to the left of your '1' key) WHILE using this `${your-variable}` around your JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch('/api/staffattendance/'+makedate+'')
```

Simply **concatenation** works for me like this

Comment: This is not a solution.