# How can I pass a variable with url on javascript fetch() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django-rest-framework, fetch-api

I have to fetch data from my django api. In the url to fetch (http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/1/edges/) there are a number (pk integer) which can change.
It can be  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/2/edges/ or
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/3/edges/. It depends on the current network.
How can I handle this integer as variable ?  I try this from ([How to pass a variable with url on javascript fetch() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50983150/how-to-pass-a-variable-with-url-on-javascript-fetch-method))
but it does not work

```
// Fetch data from api.
    var edges_from_api;
    var network_id = 1;
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/{network_id}/edges/')
        .then((response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then((data) => edges_from_api=data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use template literals

```js
    var network_id = 1;
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/network/${network_id}/edges/`)
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals