# how do i format this url so it displays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this url that I have to pass as a javascript string. I know that I need to escape the characters, but no matter what I do I can't seem to get it right?

```
 var v = "<a href="www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847">www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>";
```

Comment: The syntax highlighter shows your error

Comment: Surround it `'` instead of `"` or escape the `"` inside the string with `\"`. See [MDN: String Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#String_literals)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using double quotes inside a string declared with double quotes. You can:

- Change the double quotes *inside* the string to single quotes

> ```
> var v = "<a href='www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847'>www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>";
> ```

- Escape the double quotes inside the string with `\`

> ```
> var v = "<a href=\"www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847\">www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>";
> ```

- Change the double quotes *outside* the string to single quotes

> ```
> var v = '<a href="www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847">www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>';
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you can use single quotes `'` to differentiate internal quotes, or you can escape your internal quotes `\"`

The code becomes:

```
var v = "<a href='www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847'>www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>";
```

or

```
var v = "<a href=\"www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847\">www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this

```
var url = "www.youbigboy.com/showthread.php?t=1847"; //or other dynamic url's
var sb = "<a href='" + url + "'>big boy url</a>";
```

source: [is the + operator less performant than StringBuffer.append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112158/javascript-string-concatenation)